# Troubleshooting regional availability failures in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-app-service-plans

Today we experienced some failures from SG, BR and IE; all what seem like timeouts to our API which is hosted in the North Europe data centre:

[image: Availability]

There were no application failures on our side, so we can assume it to be a network transient-related issue between these regions and our server (North Europe).

Are there any resources that can help in confirming/troubleshooting such issues?

**EDIT:**

When drilling down into the failed request (as suggested by yonisha):

[image]

So it must have been either server/network (Azure) or application-related?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can see the failures of the availability tests:

1. Click on the failed test instance, above the chart you've provided (make sure to change the 'Time range' to at least 1 hour.[image]
2. Click on the failed request, which will open another blade with the exception details:
   [image]
3. Depending on the exception details, you can then determine whether it was server/network issue (server was unavailable etc.), application level (you may have insufficient logging to log those failures) or client side issue (client has closed the connection etc.).

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise one could drill down further. Please see the update to my question